# Find RAID controller under Linux

Tags: linux, raid, storage, drivers

I have been trying to find the RAID controller for good purpose. I need to find the right driver that works with the RAID controller.

I can assure you i have a raid system in my server, here is an output of df-h

```
/dev/md1              4.7G  140M  4.6G   3% /
tmpfs                1015M     0 1015M   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                   10M  100K   10M   1% /dev
tmpfs                1015M     0 1015M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0              134M   44M   90M  33% /boot
/dev/md5              209G   97G  113G  47% /home
/dev/md4              1.9G   33M  1.9G   2% /tmp
/dev/md2              9.4G  605M  8.8G   7% /usr
/dev/md3              4.7G  3.2G  1.5G  68% /var
```

Now i have read online that i should normally see an output of my Driver off this command :

> lspci | grep -i raid

Problem is, the prompt doesnt return me anything..

So now i am having a hard time to figure out what is my Storage system driver..

For information purpose, here is an output of lscpi alone

```
 lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation E7320 Memory Controller Hub (rev 0c)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7525/E7520/E7320 PCI Express Port A (rev 0c)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7525/E7520/E7320 PCI Express Port A1 (rev 0c)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6300ESB 64-bit PCI-X Bridge (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6300ESB USB Universal Host Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6300ESB USB Universal Host Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 6300ESB Watchdog Timer (rev 02)
00:1d.5 PIC: Intel Corporation 6300ESB I/O Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6300ESB USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 0a)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 6300ESB LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6300ESB SATA Storage Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6300ESB SMBus Controller (rev 02)
03:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541GI/PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
03:04.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541GI/PI Gigabit Ethernet Controller
04:05.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Rage XL (rev 27)
```

Thanks alot any help will be more than appreciated !

EDIT : result of cat /proc/mdstat

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md6 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      3911744 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0]
      136448 blocks [2/1] [U_]

md2 : active raid1 sda5[0] sdb5[1]
      9767424 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md3 : active raid1 sda6[0] sdb6[1]
      4883648 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md4 : active raid1 sda7[0] sdb7[1]
      1951744 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md5 : active raid1 sda8[0] sdb8[1]
      218652544 blocks [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      4883648 blocks [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Comment: The pure reality is that in your case, the software raid is nearly surely a much better option, as the hardware.

Comment: Pay good attention to `mdstat`. Your boot RAID is degraded. One disk failure could leave you with an unbootable system.

Answer (score 5):

You are using *Software* RAID -- there is no hardware controller backing that RAID. Software RAID is implemented in the Linux kernel.

You can confirm it's status by looking at `/proc/mdstat`

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

Comment: ...which you can't in the case of the sonamed "hw raids", which are exactly so sw raids, but their controlling sw is in a very lowquality, closed source, proprietary, buggy firmware, and not in the clean, public, opensource kernel.

Comment: If i understand properly, there is no Storage controller (Driver) in my system ? I have edited the post with the result of the command given above. I had used it already but seeing it give me ne result on a driver, I though it was useless.

Comment: @user3822093 There is no hardware driver; there is no hardware controller. The RAID is implemented in the kernel. The "driver" is a kernel module you can list with  `lsmod | grep raid`. Side note: `md0` is missing a disk (The `(U_)` shows this)